# EF Core using HasConversion causing DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF core to store a local copy of a database. When a row is removed from the server database I need to remove that row from the local database using EF Core. I have run into an issue on an entity that uses HasConversion to convert a string property to upper. When EF core tries to delete one of these entities a DbUpdateConcurrencyException is thrown. I think I understand what is causing the issue but I dont know how to resolve it.

The entity in question is defined like this:

```cs
    public class PartBin : BaseEpiView
    {
        public string PartNum { get; set; }
        public string WarehouseCode { get; set; }
        public string BinNum { get; set; }
        public decimal OnhandQty { get; set; }
    }
```

Now in the original database on the server the BinNum has values like "Elec101", "Elec102", "ELEC103", "elec104". Note the inconsistent capitalisation. To address this I have made use of HasConversion to convert the values to Upper.

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<PartBin>().Property(p=> p.BinNum)
           .HasConversion(v => v.ToUpper(), v => v.ToUpper());
```

This works and all the BinNum values are in Upper and displayed nicely to the user.

However the problem comes when one of these entries needs to be deleted. EF Core is throwing this error when SaveChanges() is called.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.'

I think this is caused by the HasConversion because in the database the BinNum is "Elec101" while on the entity it is "ELEC101" so EF Core thinks the data has changed and throws the exception. I need to tell EF core the data has not changed and it is ok to go ahead and delete the row...

What I have tried.

- Reading all the docs and SO questions I can find
- Remove the HasConversion which did resolve the delete issue but then all the BinNum values have inconsistent capitalistion in the local database.
- Use the IsConcurrencyToken() to tell EF Core to look at the PartNum property when considering if an entity has changed. This didnt work.

```cs
    modelBuilder.Entity<PartBin>().Property(p => p.PartNum).IsConcurrencyToken(true);
```

- On the BaseEpiView class that PartBin inherits from there is a SysRevID. This is the SQL RowVersion and is incremented by the MS SQL server. If this value has not changed then the row has not changed.

```cs
    public abstract class BaseEpiView : BaseObject, IEpiObject 
    {
        public Byte[] SysRevID { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried setting that as the RowVersion in the model Builder.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<EpicorPartBin>().Property(p => p.SysRevID).IsRowVersion();
```

but still the DbUpdateConcurrencyException is thrown.

It would seem like using the IsRowVersion() is the correct way to address this issue but it is not working for some reason? Have I implemented it incorrectly?

Other Information:

- EF Core 5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6 (I should update to a released version and check that....)
- local database is SQLite
- Server database is MS SQL Server
- EF Core is hosted in a WPF .Net Core app

Comment: Do you know why `BinNum` is currently used for concurrency checking? I mean... it doesn't look like you need to add other methods of concurrency checking. Instead you should probably first identify the existing mechanisms

Comment: @grek40 You are correct, I need to understand why BinNum is being used for concurrency check...

Turns out BinNum is part of a composite key for the entity. That means the HasConversion I had defined was completely stuffing up EF Core. It was not able to find the row because I was messing with the primary key hence the error message. I was focused on concurrency checks because most of the posts etc for that error are related to concurrency checking.

Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.
Brett

Comment: So, question solved by means of a misunderstanding? You could probably write a short answer yourself, explaining that the error message originated in a column that was part of the primary key in your case. Might help others in the future ;)